# VirtualBox 5.0 crashes on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS every time on kernel 4.13

Tags: 16.04, kernel, virtualbox

My virtualbox 5.0 use to work on kernel 4.8.13 and it was in my list of kernels to choose from.

Apparently automatic download and updates removed 4.8.13 and installed the latest kernel available 4.13.x without my knowledge.

Now, virtualbox crashes 100% of the time every time I boot one of the virtual machines. The whole host operating system (Ubuntu) FREEZES COMPLETELY. The only way is to reboot my system (power cycling).

So, I thought maybe I can install 4.8.13 and get virtualbox working again, but I DO NOT see 4.8.13 in the list of kernel images in the repository. And I thought maybe different version of 4.8.X will work. None of the old kernels I have tried so far worked to fix my problem at all. So, what am I doing wrong? What are my next steps in solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using old 5.0 version. Virtual box have released version 5.2.6 with fixes for new Linux kernel version like 4.13.

Kindly consider to manually download and install the same:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

You can refer the changelog of 5.1 and 5.2 from below link:-

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-5.1

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog

Answer (score 0):

Reboot to an older working version of the kernel by holding down the shift key during boot up. Then update the grub boot loader to default to the working older kernel. Then upgrade Virtualbox host and guest software. That at least gets you up and working again.

That's what I did. Note that I do not have this problem on different laptop hardware using the same Virtualbox host, guest additions, and Ubuntu. The other main difference between my laptops is that one runs Win7 and the other Win10 so there are other factors involved.

Comment: Eric, I was switching between working Kernel to the latest un-working kernel like you said for awhile. Well, silently my Ubuntu updated the kernel to the latest bumping off the old working Kernel. Since then I could never run Virtualbox on my ubuntu system. I kind of followed Arvind's Answer to make it work. The real issue or problem is the fact that they don't seem to keep the repository UPTO Date. I had to go to Virtualbox website and download their very latest version 5.2 and install it on the Latest Kernel. It still is Virtualbox 5.0.2 in the Ubuntu repository.